# Can't add any menu items anymore, server related

Tags: menus, server

*<sub>Unsure if this fits here, but hopefully it does.</sub>*

So I'm having an issue that I can't add any menu items to a custom menu anymore. At this very point I can verify that it's server related, since this issue is appearing now on multiple Wordpress installations, even a complete fresh one.

For the record: I have tested it, as said, on a fresh installation with the basic theme, newly downloaded Wordpress, no configuration changes, etc.

Each installation on the server has it's own wp-config, .htaccess and php.ini file and there are non in the root (`public_html/`), so neither of those can't be the issue.

I'm running a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS.

Anyone got a suggestion?

Comment: These are unpopulated menus?

Comment: what happens when you try to add a menu item?

Comment: I can add menus, but not menu items. On both existing as fresh installations. So even one item is like too many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is a guess, rather than certainty, the issues with menus typically boil down to following — working with them involves submitting large and complicated POST requests to server.

And what on server has issue with large and complicated POST requests? Security software!

The first item to check in such case is usually going to hosting support and asking if they are:

- using anything like mod_security
- does anything show up in security logs